# AngularJS $compile with jQuery clone()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, compilation

I know it's not ideal, but I'm using jQuery UI [Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/), [Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [Resizable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) within my AngularJS build.

My Draggable uses the *clone* [helper option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper), so I need to duplicate the draggable once I drop it into the Droppable element.

To do so, I use the following code.

```
$formContainer.droppable({
     'drop' : function (event, ui) {

          var clone = ui.helper.clone();

          clone.draggable({ /* ... */ });

          clone.resizable({ /* ... */ });

          clone.appendTo('#form-container');

     }
});
```

This works fine, until I need to use ng-click within the Draggable.

**The Question:** What is the mode elegant way to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) with the value of the var `clone` so that ng-click, etc still works once I've appended the new element?

Am I stuck manually passing a HTML string to `$compile` then manually updating the in-line styles / data / class attributes added to the original element from the Draggable plugin?

Comment: try to compile clone using $compile(clone)(scope)

Comment: @Jugnu Yep, I tried that. No luck. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: can you provide fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jugnu: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I was able to solve the issue with what I think is more of an "angular" approach (using data binding and directives) rather than a "jQuery" approach (manually adding elements to the DOM with the `.append()` method).

Here is a fiddle with how got everything working: http://jsfiddle.net/1knfywzr/

When I drop the draggable, I extract the required data and store it in an array. I then use `ng-repeat` to loop over the array and attach directives to the document. The directives then use the data I extracted earlier to position / size the new draggable.

I'm pretty happy with the approach as it seems a little more organised than my original idea, but I'm happy for others to share their thoughts.